# ajax post to php returns $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post newsletter form data to a `php` page with `ajax` but when I echo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` on the `php` page it prints `GET`(with no variables). I have used similar code on multiple websites with no problems. (`jquery v3.2.1`)

```
  $.ajax({
            method: 'post', 
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '<?=$site_url?>/templates/xxxx/contact_send/email_send.php',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
            contentType: 'application/JSON;charset=UTF-8',
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
```

Network log

[image: Network log]

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
[image: echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']]

Response

[image: Response]

Comment: do `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST']);` to see if your variables are anywhere.

Comment: Done that. Returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

browser of method is GET....(second image)

you should see network log image the response

Comment: so what about your problem? you call ajax post to php, it's response POST (right), and you connect to url in browser response GET (right), do you want to what result?

Comment: It doesn't pass the if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') condition plus I have no data to use in the php code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to narrow down the problem by making a new HTML file with just your javascript code in it sending some fake data and a new PHP file with just `echo $SERVER['REQUEST'];` If it works you have some extra code that's messing it up. Otherwise it's some server issue. Did you make sure that you don't have .htaccess to forbid POST? Try adding this to the .htaccess `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS`